# Google static Map hangs While Loading

Tags: android, google-maps, static

I have Static map with specific latitude and longitude.

```
 map = (ImageView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.map);

...........
..........

    private void setMap(){
            final String STATIC_MAP_API_ENDPOINT = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + Lat + "," + Long + "&zoom=13&size=640x400&markers=color:red%7C" + Lat + "," + Long;

            AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> setImageFromUrl = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    Bitmap bmp = null;
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(STATIC_MAP_API_ENDPOINT);

                    InputStream in = null;
                    try {
                        in = httpclient.execute(request).getEntity().getContent();
                        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                        in.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return bmp;
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bmp) {
                    if (bmp != null) {
                        map.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    }
                }
            };
            setImageFromUrl.execute();
        }
```

And I am setting map in an `ImageView` . Now as Title says when network is slow whole activity is hanging while loading map. Any solution?

Comment: Check the solution given below.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, However I am having other layout inside activity with map. so map should be inside an activity with other layout. Any other solution?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get what you are asking. Could you clarify more with the code?

Comment: I have A specific Lat long and Im plotting it using Google Static map api. Seems like your code is is just mark user current location.

Comment: intead of the current location, you can specify your hardcoded value in latitude and longitude variable.

Comment: Hi, I'm Looking for static map only. and as I said before I am using Static map API. Please have a look at the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the google map in a fragment in your activity. Following this will not hang up your device.

Let your activity_maps.xml be:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

      <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

<RelativeLayout/>
```

Here, you have a fragment in your activity. You can adjust as the size of your image as you want.

Your java code (MapsActivity.java):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;


    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

    mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);

    points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    // Determining Current Location

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

    if (location != null) {

         latitude = location.getLatitude();  // get current latitude

         longitude = location.getLongitude();  // get current longitude

        myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate,15);

        mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);

    }
}
```

This way you can achieve a google map in fragment and it will not hang.

Also don't forget to add permissions in Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.avl.pucc.rajasthan.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```